# How do I pass an HTML document to CodeMirror as a start value?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, formatting, codemirror

I have an HTML document stored in a string as follows :

```
var htmlAsString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>........";
```

I try to initialise my CodeMirror editor with the above HTML document as follows :

```
var cm = CodeMirror($('#some-div')[0], {
  value: htmlAsString,
  mode: "htmlmixed",
  autofocus: true,
  lineNumbers: true
});
```

However, all that does is create a Code Mirror editor with one single unclickable line that contains the `htmlAsString` string.

I obviously want my Code Mirror editor to be initialized with all of the HTML nicely xml-formatted (indentation, nesting, spacing, new lines, etc..) so that the developer can use the Code Mirror to edit/update that HTML.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML string dosnt contain any line breaks or tabs/spaces.

What you will need to do is parse your string through a HTML formatter.

CodeMirror has a formatting util by including `formatting.js`

Here is a working demo: 
http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html

You will want to execute something similar to the following code after you have initialized code mirror.

```
var cm = CodeMirror($('#some-div')[0], {
  value: htmlAsString,
  mode: "htmlmixed",
  autofocus: true,
  lineNumbers: true
});

var totalLines = cm.lineCount();  
cm.autoFormatRange({line:0, ch:0}, {line:totalLines});
```